# Tee output for avconv missing

Tags: avconv

I have two installations of avconv on ubuntu 14.04 machines. 
I believe they have both been installed from standard repositories. 
However, on one of them I have the tee output, but on the other I dont:

```
# avconv -formats|grep tee 
 avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the  Libav developers
 built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
 E tee             Multiple muxer tee
```

But on the other only this:

```
# avconv -formats|grep -i tee
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
#
```

I cant find what packet I am missing ? Any advise on how to get tee into avconv of the other machine are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference  was due to a mixup between avconv and some ffmpeg libraries on  the machine with 'tee'